# How to re-index HTML element name and ids?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating a dynamic form.  When I click on the Delete button I want the elements to be re-indexed.  For example, if I create 5 elements items1, items2, items3, items4, items5 and I delete the items3, I want the other four elements be re-indexed from 1 to 4 like items1, item2, item3, item4.

Here is my code:

```
jQuery(document).on("ready", function() {
    initAddRows();
});

function initAddRows() {
    var template = jQuery("#template"),
        dataRows = jQuery("#dataRows")

    jQuery("#btnAdd").on("click", function() {
        var newRow = template.clone(true, true),
            fieldRows = dataRows.find(".fieldRow"),
            rowNumber = fieldRows.length + 1;

        newRow.attr('id', 'row' + rowNumber).find('[id]').each(function() {             
            jQuery(this).attr("id", jQuery(this).attr("id") + rowNumber);
            jQuery(this).attr("name", jQuery(this).attr("name") + rowNumber);
            $('#itemscounter').val(+rowNumber);
        });     
        fieldRows.filter(":last").after(newRow);
    });

    dataRows.on("click", ".remove", function() {                    
        jQuery(this).parent().remove();
    });
}
```

and here is my html code:

```
<select id="items" class="items" style="width:127px; float:left;" name="items">
<select id="items2" class="items" style="width:127px; float:left;" name="items2">
<select id="items3" class="items" style="width:127px; float:left;" name="items3">
<select id="items4" class="items" style="width:127px; float:left;" name="items4">
<select id="items5" class="items" style="width:127px; float:left;" name="items5">
```

Comment: A working fiddle would make it easyer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by setting the id by attr

```
$('select.items').each(function(index){
 if ($(this).attr("id") != 'items') {
     $(this).attr("id","items" + (index + 1));
 }
});
```

Comment: your code work but i want no change in first field whose name=items and id=items

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
jQuery('select.items').each(function(index){
    this.id = 'items' + index + 1;
    this.setAttribute("name",this.id);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
$('.items').attr('id', function (index, oldID) {
    return 'items' + (parseInt(index, 10) + 1);
}).attr('name', function (index, oldName) {
    return 'items' + (parseInt(index, 10) + 1);
});
```